# Collection Group query isn't returning any data flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have set composite index and rules in console but still I'm unable to get any data. Below is snippet of my service for query.

```
_db.collectionGroup("entries")
   .where("instructors", arrayContains: _id.getUser.mailID)
   .where("branch", isEqualTo: _id.getBranch.name)
   .where("date", isEqualTo: date)
   .snapshots();
```

Comment: That code looks fine to me. Can you update your question (there's an `edit` link right under it) to show: 1) the values of `_id.getUser.mailID`, `_id.getBranch.name` and `date`, for example by printing them right before the query and copy/pasting that output in to your question, 2) a screenshot of a document that you'd expect to be returned by this query? Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the issue is resolved now